# Haskell embedded Either

Tags: haskell

I am having trouble understand the answer to this question

Exercise 4.7 Based on our definition of Tuple from the previous exercise, write a
function which takes a Tuple and returns either the value (if it’s a one-tuple), a
Haskell-pair (i.e., (’a’,5)) if it’s a two-tuple, a Haskell-triple if it’s a three-tuple
or a Haskell-quadruple if it’s a four-tuple. You will need to use the Either type to
represent this.

```
fromTuple (One a ) = Left (Left a )
fromTuple (Two a b ) = Left (Right (a,b) )
fromTuple (Three a b c ) = Right (Left (a,b,c) )
fromTuple (Four a b c d) = Right (Right (a,b,c,d))
```

with the definition of either being

```
data Either a b = Left a
                  | Right b
```

I understand the use of the Either type, but cant seem to understand how the **embedding works**.
It seems to me that more than one parameters are being passed into an either.

Comment: You should provide your definition of `Tuple`.

Comment: In e.g. `Right (Left (a,b,c) )` the constructor `Right` is passed a single argument, `Left (a,b,c)`. Similarly, `Left` is being passed a single argument, the tuple `(a,b,c)` (even if it's a tuple, it's a single value).

Comment: Two **types** are to be passed into the type definition of an Either. But when creating an Either value, you need to pass only one value, *either* the left one of the right one.

Comment: The return type of `fromTuple` is `Either (Either a b) (Either c d)` (for some appropriate types `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`). You are basically converting a 4-way sum type into a "tree" of types.

Comment: @chi I think your comment is good enough to be an answer to this question. In particular, the confusion seems to be with the tuple notation which is sometimes used as notation for passing multiple arguments in other languages. At least that is how I interpret the last sentence of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are confused by the notation

```
Right (Left (a,b,c))
```

Here, the constructor `Right` is passed a single argument, which is `Left (a,b,c)`.

Similarly, in the same expression, the constructor `Left` is being passed a single argument, the tuple `(a,b,c)`. Note that this is a single argument, even if it's a tuple.

Finally, note that the result type has the form "either-of-eithers", i.e.

```
Either (Either _ _) (Either _ _)
```

where the holes `_` must be filled with suitable types (including tuples, in some cases).